# Python | Crear un archivo y copiar el texto que hay en el otro empezando desde abajo

Tags: python

Este es el enunciado propuesto:

Crear un programa en Python que lea de un fichero de
texto (poema.txt) que se pasa como parámetro un poema.
Devolverá un nuevo fichero de texto (poema-inv.txt) con
los versos del poema invertidos.

Y este es el código que tengo hecho por ahora:

```
import sys
nombreArchivo = sys.argv[1]
f = open(nombreArchivo, "r")
lineas = f.readlines()
tamano = len(lineas)
f.close()

g = open("poema-inv.txt", "w")
for i in range(0, tamano):
    poema = lineas[i - tamano]
    g.write(poema)
g.close()
```

Se copia el texto original y no empezando desde abajo. Si muevo "i" desde esta manera `lineas[tamano - i]`, me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ejercicio2.py", line 14, in <module>
    poema = lineas[tamano - i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te ha dicho @Tomas, con [::1] debería funcionarte, igual no lo estás poniendo donde deberías:

```
import sys

nombreArchivo = sys.argv[1]

with open(nombreArchivo, "r") as f:
    lineas = f.readlines()

with open("poema-inv.txt", "w") as g:
    for i in lineas[::-1]:
        g.write(i)
```

En primer lugar mete las líneas del archivo en la lista `lineas` y posteriormente recorres esa lista hacia atrás y vas escribiéndola en el nuevo archivo.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias ! Funciono

Answer (score 1):

El error radica en la lógica dentro del for, `[i - tamano]` entregará números negativos hasta llegar al cero. En python si en una lista usas un índice negativo la lees de reverso, por ende -1 seria el ultimo -2 el anteultimo, etc.
Lo que puedes hacer es invertir la lista con las líneas de antemano y luego agregarlas a poema. Para ello hay varias formas, una de ellas es usar la función `.reverse()`

```
lineas.reverse()
```

También puedes invertirla usando `[::-1]`.

Comment: Cuando pongo `.reverse()` me sale en el documento de texto None. Y si lo pongo como `lineas[tamano].reverse()` me sale el mismo error y el `[::-1]` me sale si, pero en un formato que no necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la lógica del for:

en lugar de `for i in range(0, tamano):`

usa `for i in range(-tamano, 1):`
y al seleccionar las lineas `poema = lineas[abs(i)]`
de forma efectiva te estará leyendo a la inversa

```
for i in range(-tamano, 1):
    poema = lineas[abs(i)]
```

otra opción es negar la i y modificar el rango:

```
for i in range(1, tamano + 1):
    poema = lineas[-i]
```

de nuevo estarías leyendo a la inversa
de todos modos, me extraña que no puedas invertir la lista de lineas

```
lineas = f.readlines()
lineas = lineas.reverse()
```

o

```
lineas = lineas[::-1]
```

con lo que funcionaría tu función sin mas cambios